# Address 0x is 0 bytes after a block of size allocated valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I saw that there are many topics about it but I still struggle to understand where is my specific problem at the code..

```
   Node*first_word = get_first_random_node (LinkedList);
  unsigned int num_of_bytes = strlen (first_word->data) + 1;
  char *twit = malloc (num_of_bytes);
  *twit = '\0';
  strcat (twit, first_word->data);
  strcat (twit, " ");
```

the get_first_random_node is a legit function. It is allways return a node that his data is a string with len > 0.
Yet, I keep getting that error..

Comment: You allocated enough space for the string data plus the null byte that ends the string; you didn't allocate enough space to add a blank at the end.  You need to allocate `strlen(first_word->data) + sizeof(" "):` — the `sizeof()` is a way of writing `2`.  Using a macro `ONE` for `1` is modestly silly.  Literals 0 and 1 can be used without needing explanation.

Comment: Yep that was it. I forgot I need to include the "".. Thank you! (And yes I know it is completly silly, just new at C and didnt know when I need to use macro and when not).

Comment: We all had to learn once upon a time — longer ago for some of us than for others.  Stack Overflow didn't exist when some of us learned C.  Indeed, neither did the internet as such, and web browsers were still a decade or more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring comment into an answer.*</sup>

You allocated enough space for the string data plus the null byte that ends the string; you didn't allocate enough space to add a blank at the end. You need to allocate:

```
size_t num_of_bytes = strlen(first_word->data) + sizeof(" ");
```

The `sizeof()` is a way of writing 2; when applied to a string literal, `sizeof()` counts the null byte.

Side comment: using a macro `ONE` for `1` is modestly silly (and changing it to `#define ONE 2` so the length is right would be even sillier, but funnier things have been seen in other people's code). Literals 0 and 1 can usually be used without needing an explanation.  Yes, it's important to avoid 'magic numbers' in code, but 0 and 1 are very mundane and non-magical.